# Svn Commit Failed: Details Follow Directory ... is missing

Tags: linux, svn, unix, directory

```
$ svn commit -m "username hw_1 submission" hw_1
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Directory '~/username/username-class-xx-yy/hw_1/hw_1 is missing
svn: Directory '~/username/username-class-xx-yy/hw_1/hw_1 is missing
```

And if I try to add it again:

```
svn add hw_1
svn: warning: 'hw_1' is already under version control.
```

I have been trying to figure out what's wrong.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please list the relevant part of the local dir tree that is related to this error. I suspect you don't have hw_1/hw_1 directory (not the parent hw_1).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that.  I just deleted the extra directory.  But now what appears is svn : '.' is not a working copy.  What does this mean?

Comment: Usually this means that your WC lacks the `.svn` subdirectory.

Comment: You don't add it manually. Assuming you are in a _subdirectory_, step up a couple levels (while still staying within SVN WC) and issue `svn add` or `svn ci` from there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have deleted hw_1 directory and created new one. In order to fix it follow below steps.

1. Backup your code
2. rename existing hw_1 to hw_1_backup
3. Update hw_1 using below command, It will checkout copy of hw_1 from svn server to local

   $ svn up hw_1
4. Copy files from hw_1_backup to hw_1 directory
5. Now commit hw_1 directory files.

I hope it will help you..

--
Rahul

TecAdmin.net